# Git stash pop only if successfully stashed before

Tags: git, bash

Part of my workflow involves doing a lot of this:

- git stash changes
- git pull
- pop stashed changes
- launch mergetool to resolve conflicts

I am trying to write a script to do all of these things at once, so I can just call it from the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

# First stash our local changes
git stash

# Then git pull to update our repo
git pull

# Pop the stash
git stash pop

# Launch mergetool if necessary
git mergetool
```

The problem I'm running into is that if I run this accidentally, and there are no changes to stash, the `git stash pop` applies some (usually super old) stash. What I want to do is run `git stash pop` only if I actually stashed something before. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need the stash step for?

Comment: If I have local changes that conflict with the pull, it says 

"error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 file.ext
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting." So the stash, pull, pop way allows me to pull the changes and then merge them in via the mergetool.

Comment: so why not simply commiting?

Comment: If I commit and then pull, the merge adds another commit to git, (iirc even if it's just a fast-forward) which makes the history messier than the stash, pull, pop way, which just leaves the commits from the pull and then my own commit(s) after the merge.

Comment: Also open to better workflow suggestions :)
I haven't used git for that long, still getting the hang of it.

Comment: So i will answer how do i use it.

Comment: I used this question to create the following script https://gist.github.com/terrisgit/eaa871da2246417b042cba20e281bad6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your explanation of why do you do what you do I'd probably go for a completely different approach. First, I'd *fetch* the remote you want to use:

```
git fetch <remote> (e.g. git fetch origin)
```

And then, I'd carry out a *rebase* against a specific branch of that remote:

```
git rebase <remote>/<branch> (e.g. git rebase origin/master)
```

This would merge your changes and you'd still be able to solve any conflicts.

If you don't like this approach, you might want to use *git pull* with the *--no-commit* flag instead:

```
git pull --no-commit
```

This way no autocommit would be performed after the merge.

Comment: That sounds like a much more natural workflow, and it looks like it basically does what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

**Edit, July 2022**: Time (and Git) have moved on and depending on your Git version much of the below is not necessarily accurate any more.  One of the most important changes is that there are now `git stash push` and `git stash create` commands.  See the footnotes and comments.

---

As [Xavier Álvarez noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115175/1256452) and [codeWizard wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34114864/1256452), it's probably wiser to avoid `git stash` entirely here.  For instance I'd look at using separate `git fetch` and `git rebase` steps (see Xavier's answer), and note that rebase now has `--autostash` which essentially does just what you want, it's just not directly available via the `git pull` convenience script.<sup>1</sup>

That said, there *is* a way to do what you've asked.  It's a little bit tricky.  It would be a lot easier if `git stash save` had a "force" option similar to `git commit --allow-empty`, but it doesn't have such an option.<sup>2</sup>  Instead, what you can do is detect whether `git stash save` pushed a new stash.  This too would be a lot easier if `git stash save` had an exit status indicating whether it pushed a stash, but again it doesn't.  That means we must rely on a different trick entirely.  We start with two facts: `git rev-parse` finds SHA-1s from "references", and `git stash` uses one particular reference.

The `git rev-parse` command will translate any reference into an SHA-1:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master
2635c2b8bfc9aec07b7f023d8e3b3d02df715344
```

A reference is just a name, usually starting with `refs`, that names some SHA-1 ID.  The most common ones are branches: `refs/heads/branch`.  You may have also used tags: `refs/tags/tag`, and you have probably used remote-tracking branches like `origin/master`, which is short for the full name, `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

The `stash` script uses `refs/stash`, so we can simply run `git rev-parse refs/stash`.<sup>3</sup>  We want to run it before `git stash save`, then again after `git stash save`.  If the output changes, the `git stash save` step must have pushed a new stash onto the stash stack.

We do have to be a bit careful since if the stash stack is empty (because the last stash was popped or dropped earlier, or no stashes have ever been created yet), `git rev-parse` will give an error message and produce no SHA-1:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/stash
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/stash': unknown revision or path not in
the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Hence we actually need `git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash`, which silently produces nothing if the reference does not exist, and then we just need a little care in any shell script that uses the result:

```
oldsha=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
git stash -q save  # add options as desired here
newsha=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
if [ "$oldsha" = "$newsha" ]; then
    made_stash_entry=false
else
    made_stash_entry=true
fi
... all of your other code goes here ...
if $made_stash_entry; then git stash pop; fi
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git pull` command is basically a short-hand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, or, if you tell it, to run `git fetch` followed by the usually-more-appropriate `git rebase`.  If you break it up into its two separate steps, though, you get a lot more control, along with the ability to inspect the incoming changes before merging or rebasing.

**Edit, July 2022**: `git pull` is no longer a script and autostash works with it now.  There were intermediate transition states along the way.

<sup>2</sup>You can effectively force stash creation using the relatively new `create` and `store` subcommands: create a stash, then store the resulting SHA-1, and you've forced a stash-save even if there is nothing to stash.  But not everyone is up to date with a recent git, so for scripts, it's probably wiser to rely on the old way (or as noted earlier, not use stash at all, especially since it has various minor but annoying bugs, in various versions of Git).

**Edit, July 2022**: `git stash` is no longer a script and has new options and verbs.  See comments.

<sup>3</sup>It's wise to spell out the full name, because `git rev-parse stash` will first look for a *branch* named `stash`.  This is true in general with all references when writing aliases or scripts: spell out full names (and use `--` syntax as necessary) to make sure Git doesn't do what it *thinks* you meant, in odd corner cases.

Comment: Thank you.  In my scripting use-case, this is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: `git stash create` does not currently support the `-u` option for untracked files.  So your answer using `git stash save` is more flexible, in case untracked files are present.

Comment: @steampowered: interesting that `-u` isn't supported there. The stash code has gotten some attention lately in Git, but last time I tested it (a while ago) it was still broken for "make change in index, set work-tree to match HEAD". (And thanks for the fix for the swapped true/false state in the example!)

Comment: On recent git I get: `fatal: subcommand wasn't specified; 'push' can't be assumed due to unexpected token 'save'`

Answer (score 5):

When using `git stash save <messsage>`, the message you pass will show upon a successful save.

So one trick is to generate a timestamp, which will be used as the message, and drop the most recent stash if the timestamp was found in the resulting message.

One line:

```
t=timestamp-$(date +%s); r=$(git stash save $t); v=$(echo $r|grep $t); if [ "$v" ]; then git stash list; echo "SAVED! NOW REMOVING..."; git stash drop stash@{0}; else echo "Nothing to Stash!"; fi; echo "Stashes: "; git stash list; echo "Done!"
```

Expanded:

```
# unique timestamp
t=timestamp-$(date +%s) 

# stash with message
r=$(git stash save $t)

# check if the value exists
v=$(echo $r|grep $t)

# if the message is found...
if [ "$v" ] then 

  # DEBUG: Before
  git stash list
  echo "SAVED! NOW REMOVING..."

  # remove last stash
  git stash drop stash@{0}
else 
  echo "Nothing to Stash!"
fi

# DEBUG: after
echo "Stash List: "
git stash list
echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about running a git status first? If there are local changes, run the stash command. If not, skip it. Save this result in a bool and then don't run the pop if there was no fresh stash.

Comment: Hmm, that could work. I wonder if there's a nicer way to check if there are local changes than trying to parse the output of that though

Comment: Write a shellscript that does this for you and execute `stash pop` only on the right conditions, bobroxsox

Comment: @bobroxsox `needStash="$(git status -s)"; [[ -n "${needStash}" ]] && git stash; ! git pull; [[ -n "${needStash}" ]] && git stash pop`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar for automating merging master. I ended up just creating an empty file with a unique name. The next step was to include untracked files when stashing (`stash -u`). Now I know I can always pop, since I am creating something to stash. To finish up I delete the new file I created once everything else is done.

I then created the following aliases:

```
 up  - pull with rebase and sub-modules*
 mm  - merge master
 tm  - create file with novel name
 rtm - remove said file
```

...and the actual aliases:

```
[alias]
up           = !git pull --rebase --prune --recurse-submodules $@ && git submodule update --init --recursive && git submodule foreach git up && echo 'git on up'
mm           = "!f() { git tm; git stash -u; git co ${1-master}; git up; git co -; git merge ${1-master}; git stash pop; git rtm; }; f"
tm           = "!f() { touch __nothing_to_see_here__; }; f"
rtm          = "!f() { rm __nothing_to_see_here__; }; f"
```

*up stolen from [haacked](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/07/28/github-flow-aliases/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and resolved for Windows using the following simple script:

```
@rem The following is unsetting one environment variable if already set by (normally by previous executions of the script)
set STASH_SUCCEED=
@rem If push succeeds the variable is set
git stash push && set STASH_SUCCEED=1
@rem Do your stuff here...

if defined STASH_SUCCEED ( git stash pop && echo "STASH POPPED" )
```

Answer (score -2):

you should try to avoid stash if you are doing many things in as script, instead simply commit your code and then pull your changes.

You can also write an alias instead of a script:

```
git config --global alias.<your alias> "git add. && git commit &1 && git pull"
```

The above command will accept the commit message as parameter and will do git add , commit & pull

Comment: Committing and then pulling puts a merge commit in the history, which makes things messy. The same is not true if you first stash, then pull, then pop and finally commit. Thanks though